# Help for evaluating the line integrals with Green's Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Earlier, when I scrolled the Instagram posts I found a mathematical problem uploaded by *The Vegan Math Guy* like the following because this problem looks interesting to me to be solved. The mathematical problem is to find $\displaystyle \int\limits_C x^4 \,\mathrm dx+ xy \,\mathrm dy$ where $C$ is the area shown by the following graph.

[image: Graph for line integral]

In my solution, I'd use Green's Theorem because I've seen this line same as told in Ron Larson's calculus book at Theorem 15.8. Green's Theorem says that:

> Let $R$ be a simply connected region with a piecewise smooth boundary $C$, oriented counterclockwise (that is $C$ is traversed once so that the region $R$ always lies to the left). If $M$ and $N$ have continuous first partial derivatives in an open region containing $D$, then
> $$\displaystyle \int\limits_C M\,\mathrm dx+N\,\mathrm dy=\iint\limits_R\left( \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \right)\,\mathrm dA$$

Then I follow the steps as demonstrated in Example 1 on p. 1025, like this:

- Examine the conditions

  1. Is $C$ positively oriented? Yes.
  2. Is $C$ piecewise smooth? Yes.
  3. Is $C$ closed and simply connected? Yes.
- Find the partial derivative the function have continuous first partial derivatives.

Let $M=xy$ and $N=x^4$.
\begin{align*} \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\implies\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left[ xy \right]&=x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[y]\\&=x \\ \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\implies\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left[ x^4 \right]&=4x^3 \end{align*}

- Then taking Green's Theorem, I evaluated like this:
  \begin{align*} \displaystyle \int\limits_C x^4\,\mathrm dx+xy\,\mathrm dy&=\iint\limits_D\left( \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \right)\,\mathrm dA \\&=\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_{0}^{1-x}\left( 4x^3 \right)-x\,\mathrm dy\mathrm dx\\&= \int\limits_0^1 \left[ 4x^3y-xy \right]^{1-x}_0\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int\limits_0^1\left( 4x^3(1-x)-x(1-x) \right)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int\limits_0^1 4x^3-4x^4-x+x^2\,\mathrm dx\\&=\left[ x^4-\frac{4x^5}{5}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3} \right]_0^1\\&=1-\frac{4}{5}-\frac12+\frac13\\&=\dfrac{1}{30} \end{align*}

After evaluating the line integral, I see why my line integral is different than the one of the comments on Instagram @a_generic_nerd2 that shares his solution. This user got $\frac16$ while me $\frac{1}{30}$, because I making that taking the partial derivative of $x^4$  with respect to $x$ for $N$ and for $M$, I taking the partial derivative of $xy$ with respect to $y$, but this user does reverse from what I do on the partial derivative. In your opinion, am I doing wrong?

[Here's the link](https://www.instagram.com/p/Cxg2lmXvLsF/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link&igshid=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==) that leads to the source I mentioned in this problem.

Comment: Check the formulas you have written and think what's $M$ and what's $N$ again.

Comment: Geez.  I didn't pay attention to the formula even though I had shown it in Theorem. The $M$ is supposed to be $x^4$ and $xy$ for the $N$. So, that is supposed to be $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=0$ and $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=y$. 

Comment: It's ok. It happens.

Comment: That's what my teacher says, "You actually can pass math but one thing that made you fail on math is not reading carefully". Can I take my own answer so I can demonstrate the correct one, @TonyPizza?